# Is It possible to use Custom DNS Implementation within the Kubernetes Cluster?

Tags: kubernetes

I want to enable SSL within my Kubernetes cluster to let my Microservices communicate via TLS/SSL, but don't want to set up some Istio Infrastructure for that or some Cert-Managers (it is going to take too loong time),

Seems Like Default Kubernetes DNS Server Does Not Support SSL Internally between the Pods, So, I want to set up my own Traefik Dns Server to manage TLS/SSL certificates, does it possible to do that? (It is probably sounds weird and crazy, but I'm looking for opportunities :) if so, is there any recommendations for that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple options, either you use the internal CA of k8s or you can use the **Cert manager** first for CA purposes.

**Certmanager** would be easy to manage and create the certificates.

Certmanager CA doc : https://cert-manager.io/docs/configuration/ca/

You will get the certificate and other details into the K8s secret so you can use it as per need.

You can mount the k8s **secret**(storing the details) into the **POD** and the service can use that certificate further or else you can make your code to trust the all certs from specific **CA**.

You can also write down the Init container for creating the certificate for microservice with CA details of creating the self-singed certificates using OpenSSL or so.